# How can I securely send android location data to a server

Tags: php, android, security

I've just started to get into Android development and am currently developing an app which part of the functionality is to update the GPS location hourly. I've managed to get the app to store the location in my database by posting the values to a php file similar to the one below. The problem I'm having trouble figuring out is how to do this securely so that only values from my android app are stored and not just any data that is posted to the url.

Simplified php file that receives gps values:

```
<?php 

require_once 'connect.php';

$imei = $_POST['imei'];
$longitude = $_POST['longitude'];
$latitude = $_POST['latitude'];

$result = mysqli_query($con, "UPDATE `device_location` SET `Longitude` = '$longitude', `Latitude` = '$latitude' WHERE `IMEI` = '$imei'"); 

?>
```

Essentially, anyone who knows the url of the php file and a valid IMEI number can post fake gps values. How can I verify that the gps values are only coming from my android app?

Comment: For one you could stop introducing those sql injection holes in your code.

Comment: Yeah I know it's open to SQL injection. My actual code has measures to prevent that but I didn't see the need to post it all as it isn't really the focus of the question

Comment: Really you have no idea how to prevent sql injection. Sorry. Or do you have a reeeaally good reason (trust me you don't) you are using an ancient and obsolete database API.

Comment: Short Answer: You can't. This has been answered elsewhere. You can just make it really, really difficult for someone to figure out how you are exchanging data. The answers below give you a good starting point -- hardcoded shared secret (obfuscate it as much as possible), security token obtained from your web-app, and possibly a checksum or digest of the submitted data. All of these can be sidestepped by reverse-engineering your app. The idea is to make it so difficult that most won't try... and change the mechanism the moment you know it's been compromised.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. You can use a string that is hardcoded in your app code in server
   and in android and don't share that with anyone.
2. If you want to increment the security, you could create a string generated by yourself or  by the any library that generate a GUID (token) in the server, so when the user autenticates in android app, save the string in the database with an  expiration time (a column in the table and then verify that when the request is done, the token is valid). The token should be send in every request from the android app and when the user finish the session the token should be deleted , so when he authenticates again, get another token.

Answer (score 0):

One way is to generate a random string to be used as an access token when the user logs in to your app. Save this string in your database and make all future API calls using this string. Your server side code can then check to see if the access token is a valid one by looking it up in the database. If it's valid, then continue with the request.

Comment: I think that's a good idea, but wouldn't the access token need to be stored on the device? Which could then mean someone might be able to reverse engineer the app and retrieve the token

Comment: The token is stored in the database server side. It can also be set to expire after a set period of time and then a new one can be requested. In order to initially get a token, the user has to get through your login process.